# Область видимости переменных

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 1;

function seven() {
return this.a = 7;
}
alert(seven.prototype.a);
// [object].prototype.property loses to
// [object].property in the lookup chain. For example...

// Won't get reached, because 'a' is set in the constructor above.
seven.prototype.a = -1;

// Will get reached, even though 'b' is NOT set in the constructor.
seven.prototype.b = 8;
```

Не могу понять почему

```
alert(seven.prototype.a);
```

Не выводит `7`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prototype не так используется, как-то так надо

```
function Seven(){};
Seven.prototype.a=7;

var seven =new Seven();
console.log(seven.a);
console.log(Seven.prototype.a);
```

а у вас вообще **this.a** не задается, т.к. функция не выполняется, **seven.prototype.а** не задан.

код для медитации:

```
function seven() {
  alert("Constructor fired!"); //не запустится, пока не сделаете что-то типа seven();
  return this.a = 7;
}

alert(seven.prototype.a); //undefined
```